# SwiftUI: TextBox text field not showing bound value until clicked

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to create a view where a user can edit an item inside of a list.
The list is displayed using a `ForEach` loop from a bound list variable, where each item is wrapped in a `NavigationLink` to a `View` that can be used to edit the given item.

The first issue I ran into was that the edit view was binding directly to the element in the list, meaning that when I edited it, it forced a reload of the previous list `View` and threw you out of the edit view after each character typed.
To get over this I though that I could duplicate the data inside of the bound variable, set this as a new `@State` variable, which would hold the updated information the user enters, and then once they are finished, update the bound variable in one go.

This is working for me, bar one small issue, which is that the variable in the `TextField` does not reflect the actual information of the bound variable, until you tap it, then it updates with the right value. Is there something I can do so that I do not have to tap for the correct value to show up? It seems odd behaviour to me, because I am also using a `ColorPicker` and this always has the correct value.

```
class AppData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var things: [Thing] = [
        Thing(name: "1", color: .red),
        Thing(name: "2", color: .blue)
    ]
}

@main
struct ThingApp: App {
    @ObservedObject private var appData = AppData()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ViewOne(things: $appData.things)
        }
    }
}


struct ViewOne: View {
    @Binding var things: [Thing]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ViewTwo(things: $things)
        }
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @Binding var things: [Thing]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ThingListView(things: $things)) {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
        }
    }
}

struct ThingListView: View {
    @Binding var things: [Thing]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach($things) { $thing in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ThingEditView(thingData: $thing.data)) {
                        Text(thing.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThingEditView: View {
    @Binding var thingData: Thing.Data
    @State private var newData: Thing.Data = Thing.Data()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $newData.name)
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $newData.color)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            newData.name = thingData.name
            newData.color = thingData.color
        }
        .onDisappear{
            thingData = newData
        }
    }
}

struct Thing: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var color: Color
    
    struct Data {
        var name: String = ""
        var color: Color = .green
    }
    
    var data: Data {
        get { return Data(name: self.name, color: self.color)}
        set {
            name = newValue.name
            color = newValue.color
        }
    }
    
    internal init (data: Data) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = data.name
        self.color = data.color
    }
    
    internal init (
        id: UUID = UUID(),
        name: String,
        color: Color
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `Thing` -- that is likely pretty important to diagnosing the issue (and making sure you have a [mre])?

Comment: "The first issue I ran into was that the edit view was binding directly to the element in the list, meaning that when I edited it, it forced a reload of the previous list View and threw you out of the edit view after each character typed." -- this signals an issue with code you haven't shown here. If I use your code, as written, and just change it to a simple Binding to `Thing`, it works fine. But, it relies on a container view that I wrote since you didn't include that in your code. Again, I'd suggest a [mre] so that people can give you a specific issue that definitely covers your scenario.

Comment: To me is the minimal reproducible example - otherwise I would be including lots and lots of source around this code that is not needed and would take away from the specific question that I am asking. I am able to reproduce the issue with just these code snippets.

Comment: No, you cannot. For example, there's no `NavigationView`. There's also no source of `Thing` objects - all you have is a `Binding`, which relies on a source from somewhere else. If someone chooses to make a container view for them (like I described that I did), it becomes a reproducible example. That's also where I discovered that a simple binding to `Thing` avoids the issue I quoted. I do agree that with your included code (and the code you're requiring people to create), the issue with the text field not changing until a click happens. But, I think that's avoidable by fixing the quoted issue.

Comment: I think there are two routes to go: 1) Fix the issue with your current approach 2) Fix the underlying issue that caused your first issue (the one I quoted) to not work. The second is what I would personally recommend, but of course that is personal preference.

Comment: The underlying issue that caused my first approach not to work is built into how SwiftUI works. Any update to a bound variable in Swift causes the providing view to update, this in turn causes my list to be re-drawn, throwing me out of the edit view. I am not sure how you have suggested a fix to this fundamental property of SwiftUI. I do not really understand what you mean by a container view, and so don't really understand what you are suggesting because binding directly to ```Thing``` causes the issue above.

Comment: I've added an answer that works fine for me. If that doesn't fit your requirement for some reason, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the basic code surrounding the code I have already provided, as trying the code snipped that you provide in your answer I also get the same behaviour as you, but when used in the updated configuration, I get my original issue.

Comment: Okay. I'll note that your edited code still isn't reproducible, as `ViewOne` relies on a parent view that has the original `[Thing]` that `ViewOne` has a binding to.

Comment: Added the final view that is relied upon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242927/discussion-between-benrichi-and-jnpdx).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you don't need the whole `data` stuff in your `Thing`. You can just pass down the thing from the `NavigationLink` like this in `ThingListView`:

```
   NavigationLink(destination: ThingEditView(thing: $thing)) {
```

and do the following in `ThingEditView`:

```
struct ThingEditView: View {
    @Binding var thing: Thing
    
    @State private var newData: Thing  // can be of type Thing too
    
    init(thing: Binding<Thing>) {  // the init puts the initial values into newData
        self._thing = thing
        self._newData = State(initialValue: thing.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Details")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $newData.name)
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $newData.color)
            }
        }
        .onDisappear{
            thing = newData
        }
    }
}
```

On a general note you might use `.environmentObject` instead of passing down `thing` from view to view.

Comment: Using the `init` worked perfectly, I had tried this before, I was assigning to `self.newData` and also wasn't using the `State` object to set it's initial value. Now the text in the TextField shows up correctly, and the change is reflected in the list when I am done editing. Would you mind educating me on why my version didn't work? Is it that using `onAppear` is too late?

Comment: I am also reading up on `EnvironmentObject` now and this looks like something I could definitely do with, so thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I was testing a while ... can't explain. If you put a `Text` in your list it shows the right value. Seems to be an issue with TextField and the getter / Setter.